# What's wrong with the tx circuit?

Tags: wireless, transmission

[image: Wireless power transfer]

Whenever I connect the power source, the transformer heats up, measures 0v AC and rectifier doesn't measure any voltage in DC.
I feel there are components I need to add to the tx circuit. I'm trying to go as cheap as I can as it is my university project

Comment: You appear to have two transformers in your diagram. You should also rotate your diagram so it's easier to read. You also give no mention of the incoming AC voltage and frequency. Going as cheap as you can is usually a task best suited to experienced engineers.

Comment: Can you add a picture of your actual setup, and confirm you are trying to setup a wireless charging/power transfer circuit?

Comment: It would also be very useful to know the transformer output voltage, and the dimensions and number of turns in L1 & L2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source is 50/60Hz mains, and your diagram is accurate (so there is no iron core between L1 and L2), then L1 will have a very low inductance and act as a hard short across the transformer.  This will cause the heating.  There will also be minimal coupling from L1 to L2, so there will be little if any voltage over L2.

For plain air coupling to work, you are likely to need a much high frequency than simple 50Hz/60Hz mains.

Alternatively, you could add a large soft iron core to L1, and then place L2 just above the end of that core.  The iron core will both limit the current flow in the primary circuit, but also "focus" the magnetic field in a way that will greatly enhance the coupling.  Think of it like an AC electromagnet, with L2 just coupling into the varying magnetic field generated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are using a conventional transformer, followed by two inductors of 1 mH each, which you think are acting as a second transformer.

First, two discrete inductors have very little magnetic coupling, even if you tape them together. This means that as far as the circuit is concerned, L1 is sitting in isolation.

Second, the impedance of an inductor is 2*pi*f*L. If you do the math, you'll see that the impedance is about 0.4 ohms. If you are producing 12 volts from the transformer, your inductor will (at best) draw about 30 amps. More likely, the transformer AND the inductor will saturate. I'm very surprised that you do not report severe buzzing from the transformer.